# How can one test user input from a JPanel?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jframe, jtextfield

I am trying to form a simple login database with SQL (mySQL workbench) and Java (Eclipse). I am not sure how to test the string input (JTextField and JPasswordField) against the database in SQL on even against any other strings.

I would like Java to print a statement out if the login credentials are equal to specified strings. Here is my current code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.*;


public class Hello1 extends JFrame {




private static final long serialVersionUID = 1487932324102279819L;


public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame Demo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(350,200);



    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.add(panel);
    placeComponents(panel);

    frame.setVisible(true);

    String username0 = "java";
    String password = "password";

    Statement stmt = null;
    try{
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javabase?useSSL=false";
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username0, password);
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs;
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from userids ");
        while(rs.next()) {
            String user = rs.getString("username");
            String pass = rs.getString("paswrd");
            System.out.println(user);
            System.out.println(pass);
        }
        connection.close();

        }

        catch (Exception e) {
             System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
             System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
     }



private static void placeComponents(JPanel panel) {

    panel.setLayout(null);
    JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("Username");
    userLabel.setBounds(10,20,80,25);
    panel.add(userLabel);

    JTextField userText = new JTextField(20);
    userText.setBounds(100, 20, 165, 25);
    panel.add(userText);
    String user = userText.getText();       

    JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
    passwordLabel.setBounds(10,50,80,25);
    panel.add(passwordLabel);

    JPasswordField passwordText = new JPasswordField(20);
    passwordText.setBounds(100,50,165,25);
    panel.add(passwordText);
    String pass = passwordText.getSelectedText();

    if(user.equals('b') && pass.equals('t')){
        System.out.println("Correct Login");
    }
    System.out.println(pass);

    JButton loginB = new JButton("Login");
    loginB.setBounds(10, 80, 80, 25);
    panel.add(loginB);


}

}
```

I have tried getting the text in each userText/passwordText by using the .getText() and .getSelectedText() methods.

Comment: And where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @GhostCat I was stuck on how to use the button to call a class that would check the username and password against ones in the SQL databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then you need to get password when you click on the `Login` button.

Please add below code in `placeComponents` method after initializing the button.

```
loginB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            char[] pass = passwordText.getPassword();
            System.out.println(pass);
        }
    });
```

Action listeners are probably the easiest — and most common — event handlers to implement. You implement an action listener to define what should be done when an user performs certain operation.

You can read more on ActionListener [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html).

You can refer [this example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html)  to see how to use password field.

Comment: Thank you very much for the swift and useful response. I'll test it out.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the username and password as parameters in the prepared statement and execute it then check whether there is a match using:

```
public void login(String user,String pass){
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javabase?useSSL=false";
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username0, password);
    PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * from userids where username=? and password=? ");
    stmt.setString(1, user);
    stmt.setString(2, pass);
    ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery();

    if(rs.hasNext()){
    //continue with operation
    }else{
    //show user doesn't exist
    }
}
```

Then Add the event to the button:

```
loginB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
String user = userTextBox.getText().toString();
char[] pass = passwordText.getPassword();
            login(user,pass);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why do we have to use "String" for the username and "char[]" for the password? Is it because we're using a password field? I appreciate your answer.